# Make something disappear for everyone besides admin

Tags: php, html

How do I make something disappear for everyone besides the admin, I have this code but it only works when you are not logged in when I log in with another user it keeps showing me.

```
<?php

   if( isset($_SESSION['username']) == "admin"){
                        
   }else{   
     echo "<style> .add{display: none} </style>";
   } 
                   
?>
```

Comment: `isset()` returns true or false so comparing it to `"admin"` isn't what you expect.

Comment: Hi Jimbolas. Please seek articles on user management in PHP, RBAC, for example: https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps, First you check if username `isset`, then you compare it. In your code, you are comparing a `boolean` returned by `isset` to a `string` that is `"admin"`, try this:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) {
    // username is set
    if ($_SESSION['username'] == "admin") {
        // user is admin
    } else {
        echo("<style> .add {display:none} </style>");
    }
}
```

Also if it is something you want to not have in the page, using `display: none` is very shallow. Someone can just use inspect element to style it and get it to show.